# how are IDLs useful for cpis?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

i'm trying to understand if IDLs csn be useful for cross-platform invocations between the anchor and Solana programs

Answer (score 1):

IDLs are a client side concept. You don't need an IDL for calling between different programs because you can just import the function and structs needed from a crate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question. The natural reply would be to ask in what way you want to use it. The only use case I can think of for CPIs would be to compare Caller and Callee privileges(i.e confirming that an account that's expected to be mutable in the Callee program is made mutable in the Caller program).

Comment: i want to use it to call `stake` function on marinade.

Comment: In this case I don't think an IDL is needed or even useful.